# Google Sheets add-on fails to add its menu items when installed from market

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, oauth

I trying to publish Google Sheets editor add-on to the market.
It is being rejected for listing as the addon menu items are not being added to Sheets addon menu. This is the image I got from the review team: [image]

Menu items are being added within `onOpen()` trigger function, and in development environment its working fine.

The first time publishing was rejected as I was not aware for the `onOpen` ScriptApp.AuthMode restrictions and the necessity to implement `onInstall()` just to call `onOpen()`, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene).

After implementing `onInstall()` and resubmission, this was rejected again as it is still not working. The GCP error console shows onOpen() is running as a trigger, and not because it is called by the `onInstall()` which looks like is not being fired at all.

The code is:

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
  console.log("FA onInstall...");
}

function onOpen(){
  console.log("FA onOpen...");
  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Trace precedents', functionName: 'tracePrecedents'},
    {name: 'Trace dependents', functionName: 'traceDependents'}
    ];
  spreadsheet.addMenu (AppName, menuItems);

}
```

I can see I `onOpen()` is defined without parameter, it is with no special reason - just inattention. I assume this is not the problem.

In the cloud console, it looks like `onInstall()` is not fired. You can see only `onOpen()` in the executions logs, and in the cloud error you can see `onOpen()` permissions issue, which makes sense if the `onInstall()` is not called.

The image below shows the cloud executions, logging and error entries referring the google review team operations. I actually assume, but can not be 100% sure, these logs entries in the image actually refer to the Google team review operations. I just filtered the log entries by time, according to the rejection mail time I got from the review team, plus the fact I didn't do anything at that time (so no entries "belong to me" appear around that time, so it helped as well.

[image]

The following is the corresponding error log entry filtered by *"Exception: You do not have permission"* in JSON format

> {
> "insertId": "-vw46i0f1p6gav",
> "jsonPayload": {
> "message": "Exception: You do not have permission to perform that action.\n    at addMenu(src/macros:27:36)\n    at onOpen(src/macros:16:3)",
> "context": {
> "reportLocation": {
> "lineNumber": 27,
> "functionName": "addMenu",
> "filePath": "src/macros"
> }
> },
> "serviceContext": {
> "service": "AKfycbx5HHHMsaYBlD39Pf3UmyM0JhkFUWIpxU0Iw3Jp-XYCBw"
> }
> },
> "resource": {
> "type": "app_script_function",
> "labels": {
> "invocation_type": "simple trigger",
> "function_name": "onOpen",
> "project_id": "gothic-space-325413"
> }
> },
> "timestamp": "2021-11-24T20:49:50.684Z",
> "severity": "ERROR",
> "labels": {
> "script.googleapis.com/deployment_id": "AKfycbx5HHHMsaYBlD39Pf3UmyM0JhkFUWIpxU0Iw3Jp-XYCBw",
> "script.googleapis.com/process_id": "EAEA1GOytih2wJPcuJNmCqsYzsqHKmik2d0KexhRdxq9Bi-T9frqnuGYZ_0XT1d0rvTIF6w5AWR5km2z2arNDWNHrShY88Z1ZvRKKib5hX46-e1oqdrpz0T7Fxc7xNnOrWXglwuTsdOQp0CbTO-4KgutgMRotiOjwArel5QOYPKYkhD8Jb-oJ6mYPa__KPLAug-Li3IzIbR_g5y9YffLMHhY-Chd_SlfcaxuB607i30zSFjBdmtYnQreN5KXKUzfXJ60SHHNtLPZZVeaozQDB6roqP82bgzZliyU7X12Y",
> "script.googleapis.com/project_key": "MVmLkhkHw02MpGp6YjTYdgIJQT15o7EEE",
> "script.googleapis.com/user_key": "APrZfepJTnqDE2xPOOZyy7vfu7vWpovS3THrJ8F1CIHw5sc/710lPeQ940fg7V6II4bRKBAqBvr2"
> },
> "logName": "projects/gothic-space-325413/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs",
> "receiveTimestamp": "2021-11-24T20:49:51.726293367Z"
> }

questions:

1. It is right to assume `onInstall()` is not running, according to cloud error and logging? If yes - what can be the reason?

   I thought maybe, this is something with what the review team did, or maybe did not do. For example:
   First time they installed the addon, so it is being added to the main menu (i.e. *Formula Analyzer*), but the sub items are missing because of the missing `onInstall()`. Second review they just open the document again, so *Formula Analyzer* is still there, but the `onOpen` fails (again) because they did not re-install the addon. Just an assumption - I do not know of course if it is a valid scenario, or what they are actually doing..
2. More importantly maybe, this is a scenario I was considering before, how to test-imitate market installation in dev environment, without add on is published yet. How can one test the onInstall trigger? I couldn't still find the way.
   This is why after the first rejection and the fix, I published for review again, without actually testing it. I tried asking the review team, if it is possible and how, but they ignore. And here we are again.
3. How to solve this?

Comment: This looks like Apps Script bug, because according to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installing): `When an editor add-on is installed from the store, its onInstall(e) function runs in AuthMode.FULL.`

Comment: @kos not sure I understand. I understand how it should work, but something is broken obviously.

Comment: Do you have any code outside functions? All code outside functions will execute when you open the document, and if there's something there that requires authorization, it will fail. So, can you clarify this, providing the code in global scope? Also, can you provide the code where `AppName` is declared?

Comment: @Iamblichus Beside const declarations there is no code outside functions. _AppName_ is one of them `const AppName = "Formula Analyzer";` . However, as I understand it, even if there was some authorization dependent code: **1)** Some exceptions are expected in the error console. Isnt it? **2)** Would that (missing authorization while opening) prevent the `onInstall` trigger, which supposed to be fired while installing from the market, _after_ the document was open and allegedly authorization issues took place? As I understand, this is the issue - `onInstall` is not fired. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Iamblichus In addition, one of the declared const is `const _SS = (() => SpreadsheetApp.getActive());` I actually not sure when exactly this will run. const are assigned first, but I think the function itself will be executed only when called. Also I am not sure if this code requires authorization. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @OJNSim Can you expand the log with `Exception: You do not have permission...` and provide the full log here?

Comment: @Iamblichus I added the post the relevant log entry.  There are just 5 similar entries from different times in the full log. I can post all here, but it look a mass, and as far as I can tell they are completely identical apart from the date-time signature. I guess all correspond to the review team operations. it looks like it comes from `onOpen` simple trigger, and not by `onInstall`, thus - `addMenu` fails for missing permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

If the add-on is not enabled for current document and it's just installed, `onOpen` trigger does not have access to that document.

#### Explanation:

Before using an add-on for the first time in a document, it is not enabled for that document. In those cases, a simple `onOpen` does not have access to that document, and methods related to that document, like [SpreadsheetApp.getActive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive) or [Spreadsheet.addMenu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addmenuname,-submenus), fail accordingly.

Since an add-on can be installed without calling `onOpen`, when you later call `onOpen`, it may not run with `AuthMode.FULL` (the authorization mode for `onInstall`).

Therefore, an add-on should be designed so that the `onOpen` trigger can run with `AuthMode.NONE` (that is, in cases when the add-on is installed for the user, but not enabled for the document), and the review team is right in attempting to execute this without `onInstall`. And because of this, methods that access the current document should not be used in that function.

That's the reason why methods like [Spreadsheet.addMenu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addmenuname,-submenus) are not used in the documentation code snippets for editor add-ons, and [Ui.createAddonMenu()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#createaddonmenu) is used instead, since that method is not accessing the document, and so can be used in `onOpen`.

#### Code sample:

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu();
  menu.addItem('Trace precedents', 'tracePrecedents');
  menu.addItem('Trace dependents', 'traceDependents');
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

#### Note:

You'll notice that this method doesn't allow you to name the menu. That's because, since this is designed for add-ons, the menu name will match the add-on name.

#### Further reading:

- [Custom menus for editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/menus)
- [Installed versus enabled](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled)
- [Authorization modes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes)

Comment: @lamblichus so just to be sure I perfectly understand. 1) Review team did not install (actually re-install) addon, reason why `onInstall` was not fired 2) I modified `onOpen` by your advise and now when  `Run -> Test as add-on` and selecting `installed for current user` menu items are added in the selected spreadsheet. Until now, when setting `installed for current user` add-on menus were not added, and I just  ignored it as I didn't really understood or knew what to do with it. Now I do 3)  name in the menu was never `AppName` but script name as u said, even as I added the menu before

Comment: @OJNSim (1) I'm not sure what the review team did, but for sure they tested the add-on with `AuthMode.NONE`, which is quite appropriate, (2) this confirms that was the issue, since when you test with `installed for current user` it's executing with `AuthMode.NONE` and that means current document is not accessible to `onOpen`, (3) fair enough, I guess if you try to use `addMenu` in an add-on, the add-on (or script) name overwrites the parameter you provide.